# How to upload and show images after click OK in open file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, image, file-upload

I want to upload and show images after click OK(choose file) in open file, but I don't know how.

```html
<img id="img1" class="img-thumbnail" />
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1"  runat="server" />
```

I think it's same follow.

```
 protected void FileUpload1.OK(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
//Get extension file : png or PNG
            string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
            if (fileExt == ".png" || fileExt == ".PNG")
            {
                try
                {
        //get file name of images
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                    // save images in folder and file name + extension
                    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UI/User_IMG/") + fileName + ".png");
                    // show image in img tag
                   img1.src = "~/UI/User_IMG/" + fileName + ".png";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string script = "alert(" + ex.Message.ToString() + ");";
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                string script = "alert(\"File not PNG !\");";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string script = "alert(\"Please choose file !\");";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);
        }
    }
```

But it's not working. If you have a idea or solution about this, please share with me.

Comment: Never heard of `FileUpload1.Ok`! How you got into this??

Comment: show us your `asp:Button`

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, you need to display images as soon as it is `Uploaded`. So for that you can see the below code:-

We can achieve this *using client side JavaScript*

Here you go:-

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <cc1:AsyncFileUpload OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" runat="server" ID="AsyncFileUpload1"
        Width="400px" UploaderStyle="Modern" CompleteBackColor="White" UploadingBackColor="#CCFFFF" ThrobberID="imgLoader" OnUploadedComplete="FileUploadComplete" OnClientUploadStarted = "uploadStarted"/>
    <asp:Image ID="imgLoader" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/loader.gif" />
    <br /><br />
    <img id = "imgDisplay" alt="" src="" style = "display:none"/>
</form>
```

Also see the `Code Behind`.

```
 protected string UploadFolderPath = "~/Uploads/";
  protected void FileUploadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(AsyncFileUpload1.FileName);
        AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(this.UploadFolderPath) + filename);
    }
```

For more information. Please see the [reference documentatiom](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-image-after-upload-without-page-refresh-or-postback-using-ASP.Net-AsyncFileUpload-Control.aspx)

Hope that helps.